# Check case insentively if a value is in an array, and if the case doesn't match, replace it with the new value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to replace the values in an array with the correct case sensitivity. This is because I am attempting to correct user inputs. I retrieve the correct casing from a page, and the user will have an array of values, some of which will be incorrect.

Ex:

```
userValues = ["apple321", "orange_22", "pineApple" , "Cantelope", "grASShopper_9000"];
var value1 = "Apple321";
var value2 = "orange_22";
var value3 = "Cantelope";
var value4 = "GrassHopper_9000";
```

Then after some function ran through all the values, the result would be:

```
userValues = ["Apple321", "orange_22", "pineApple" , "Cantelope", "GrassHopper_9000"];
```

The reason I have `value1`, `value2`, etc is because I've already created a loop to run through an object. Just not sure how to compare the resulting values. Here is what I have already however:

```
// When the user enters data, it's sometimes case insensitive. This normalizes the data.
function NormalizeData(downloaded_data)
{
    $.each(downloaded_data, function(website,streams){
        $.each(streams, function(stream_name,value){
            stream_list[website] // This is the global variable array
            value.displayName; // This is the value I need to check case sensitivity, and replace with the new case if different
        });
    });
}
```

Here is the requested data structure:

```
downloaded_data = {
    twitch_tv : {
        timthetatman : {
            Online: "1",
            Website: "twitch_tv",
            displayName: "TimTheTatman"
        }
    }
}

streamlist = {
    twitch_tv : {
        ["timthetatman"]
    }
    hitbox_tv: {
        []
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to lowercase both values and then compare them. Use . toLowerCase()

Comment: Yes, but if I lowercase the value from `stream_list[website]`, how do I correctly reference it, since it might containing uppercase letters?

Comment: So it's problem with keys, right? The keys are then ones that case sensetive?

Comment: The array `stream_list[website]` needs to have its values replaced. The `value` result from `downloaded_data` has the correct case

Comment: Could you give a sample of your data structure in the question (input data `downloaded_data` and `stream_list`)?

Comment: I added the data structure to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Since I am using an array for the values I want to change, and not an object, it's actually much simpler than I thought. I ran a loop on every value, and if the lowercase of both values matched, but the non-lowercase values didn't, I replaced it in the array, using the numerical key as a reference.

```
function NormalizeData(downloaded_data)
{   
    $.each(downloaded_data, function(website,streams){
        $.each(streams, function(stream_name,value){
            $.each(stream_list[website], function(arrKey,arrVal){
                if(arrVal.toLowerCase() == stream_name.toLowerCase() && stream_list[website][arrKey] !== value.displayName)
                    stream_list[website][arrKey] = value.displayName;
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Here it is, simplified, if the array is called `Array1` and the value `Value1`:

```
var Array1 = ["apple"];
var Value1 = ["Apple"];
$.each(Array1, function(arrKey,arrVal){
    if(arrVal.toLowerCase() == Value1.toLowerCase() && arrVal !== Value1)
        Array1[arrKey] = Value1;
});
```